# Using a custom AndroidManifest on a Qt app for Android without using qmake?

Tags: android, c++, qt, cmake, android-manifest

I'm using Qt Creator on openSUSE Tumbleweed

I have been trying to change my Qt app's icon and name. "Projects > Android > Create Templates" works only for qmake projects. I'm using CMake with some (not Qt related) CMake Modules, so I cant use qmake.

I tried using [qt-android-cmake](https://github.com/LaurentGomila/qt-android-cmake/), but fails with error `No target architecture defined in json file`, and even after fixing the json file, doesn't output an APK file.

Also tried setting `DISTFILES` on CMake but also didn't work.

Is this even possible to do without qmake?

Comment: As a workaround: Try using Qt 5.13. I'm only getting the error with 5.14 and later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Qt 5.14, Qt 5.15 or higher, then the "`No target architecture defined in json file`" error with `qt-android-cmake` is due to a bug: [qt-android-cmake issue #35](https://github.com/LaurentGomila/qt-android-cmake/issues/35).

A fix was [merged on 2020-06-02](https://github.com/LaurentGomila/qt-android-cmake/pull/39#event-3399045239). So, update your `qt-android-cmake` and try again.